# Magento Extension/Theme Packaging

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

just a quick developer question in regards to Magento Extension/Theme Packaging, more specifically, when packaging, would I place the template files, layout files, skin folders etc in the base folder (see path below)(and not overriding any core files either)

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout

skin/frontend/base/default/css
```

and so on? I see this would be most suitable as alot of platform users would have custom themes with maybe custom namespaces for the theme folders. As users would have to stuff around to rename/move files/folders to work with their platform if packaged the default way I have seen in the past (ie in the default/default folder paths).

cheers for any feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way to package extension to use base/default or default/default location for template, layout and skin folders. Because if custom theme is used, then also this will work due to Magento's fallback mechanism. And if user want to add those files in custom theme location, then he/she should manually copy or move files in theme's respective location as you have said. And it is obvious that we can not predict custom theme path while packaging extension.

Comment: So its safe to use default/default as magento will fallback to default/default if files are not found in the custom template path?

Comment: @BenHall, Yes. Exactly